# Get a list of all unique tags in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am beginning with mongodb and have a collection with documents that look like the following

```
{
    "type": 1,
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}
{
    "type": 2,
    "tags": ["tag2", "tag3"]
}
{
    "type": 3,
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag3"]
}
{
    "type": 1,
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag4"]
}
```

With this, I want a *set* of all the tags for a particular type. For example, for type 1, I want the set of `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4` (any order).

All I could think of is to get the tags and add them to a `set` in python, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do it with mongodb's mapreduce or something else. Please advise.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you just want a (distinct) list of the tags then using distinct will be best. Map/Reduce will be slower and can't use an index for the javascript part.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

`db.coll.distinct("tags", {type:1})` Will return a set of tags for type=1.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, a Map/Reduce might work for what you are trying to accomplish, but a Set might be faster and less code.

```
> m =     function() {
...         for (var tag in this.tags) {
...             emit(this.tags[tag], 1);
...         }
...     }

> r =     function(key, values) {
...         return 1;
...     }

> db.tags.mapReduce(m, r).find()
{ "_id" : "tag1", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "tag2", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "tag3", "value" : 1 }
```

Comment: after doing this, I will still have to use the `set` method to get the list of tags in a way I need, so why even use a map-reduce step? Why not just do a `.find({}, {tags:1})` and operate on them...

Comment: How do you need the tags returned back? You didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: oops, thought it was clear, guess not... I want them in a list or a set (any iterable basically), of the tags, with no repetitions, i.e., distinct values only

Comment: The above code would give you that. Your python code would get back an array of dicts, and you could reference each tag by something like tags['_id'].

Comment: This is a count, not a distinct set of tags for the given type. It does way more work than what needs to be done. Also, you should be using a query to restrict the values by type so you don't map all values.