# Content tagging with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, tagging

I want to implement content tagging using MongoDB. In a relational database, the best approach would be to have a many-to-many relation between the **content** (say, "products") and **tags** tables. But what is best approach with NoSQL databases?

Would it be better to put every tag in a *tags* array of the "content" document, or put references to *tags* in a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement post tags in Mongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455685/how-to-implement-post-tags-in-mongo)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases where you have a n:m relation in MongoDB, you should use embedding instead of referencing. So I would recommend you to have an array "tags" in each product with the tag names. I assume that looking at a single product will be the most frequent use-case in your system. This design will allow you to show the user a product with a list of tag names with a single database query.

When you need some additional meta-data about the tags which you don't want to bind to a product (like a long-text description of a tag), you could create an additional tags collection, where the name field gets an unique index for fast lookup and avoiding duplicates. When the user clicks on or hovers over a tag name, you can use an additional query to get the tag details.

A problematic case in this design is the situation when you want to delete or rename a tag. Then you have to edit every product which includes the tag. But because MongoDB doesn't know foreign keys with CASCADE ON DELETE like SQL databases, you will always have that problem when you have documents referencing one another.

Renaming tags could be made easier by storing objectIDs instead of names in the tag array of the product. But IDs have the disadvantage that they are useless for the user. You need to get the names of the tags to show a product page. That means that you have to request every single one from the tags collection, which requires an additional database query.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to say "In most cases" when advising on embedding vs. linking.  It really depends on the use case, and while for tags it's clear that embedding is correct, for other n:m relationships embedding may be terribly incorrect.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky what you suggest?

Comment: in this case, I suggest embedding, I'm objecting to the suggestion that it would be right to embed in "most cases".

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Should there be a concern about duplication overhead of storing the same string tags in multiple products? So, if a particular tag is used very widely across products then might it be better to store tags in a separate collection per document and store an array of tagIds in the product?

Comment: First, how big are tags compared to tag Ids? Second I'm assuming you want to optimize for performance not disk storage size? BTW, for long discussion, Google group MongoDB-users would be better

Comment: Or you can memoize your `find-tag-by-id` function and avoid embedding, still.

Comment: Why store as an array over storing as a comma-separated list?

Comment: @MaxHodges A comma-separated list can not be indexed. When you want to find all documents with a specific tag, the database will have no choice than to do a full collection scan and examine every single tag-string if the substring occurs. When the collection is large, this query will take extremely long. But arrays, on the other hand, can be indexed. An index on an array will index every array element separately, so finding all documents with a specific tag by index is fast.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, I'm not sure if that is true for Mongo. `MongoDB provides text indexes to support text search of string content in documents of a collection.

text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements. To perform queries that access the text index, use the $text query operator.` source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: Sure, you could use a text index, but 1. you can only have one text index per collection, so you might want to use it for something more appropriate (like the product description) and 2. a text index is designed for actual text and not for parsing CSV. Sure, when each of your tags is only one word it could work, but when you have tags with spaces or hyphens, it will break.

Comment: Storing ObjectIds in an array seems to be the clearest way, yes, you will always have to fetch the tag list in order to interpret the IDs but if the number of tags are not hundreds is not at all a terrible scenario in comparison with having to map the whole list when editing a tag. As always it depends on the case, but generally tag lists are lightweight