# How to update sub field of document?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, data-modeling

I have a Mongo collection called "Companies". Here's an example entry:

```
{
    name: 'Company 1', 
    createdAt: new Date(), 
    tags: [
            {tag: 'tag 1', count: 63}, 
            {tag: 'tag 2', count: 47}, 
            {tag: 'tag 3', count: 13}
        ] 
}
```

Company's tags are saved in an array of objects where each tag has a count property, which remembers how often the tag was clicked. I would like to increment the count when a user clicks on the tag. I am doing this inside the event handler function. The way I tried to achieve this :

Step 1: Find the relevant company document. The tag is an "a href element" inside a list element inside a container-div. Inside that div I can find the name of the company, so I use that name to get the relevant document:

```js
var companyName = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].textContent;
var company = Companies.findOne({name: companyName});
```

This works, but I imagine that there's a cleaner solution; I don't like the children[1] part. Any recommendations?

Step 2: Now that I have the company I would like to increment the tag that was clicked. That is nasty because I need to select the right element of the array to update. I have the text of the tag (from `event.target.text`) but how do I select the right object form the tags-array? I think it has something to do with the the positional `$` operator, but I do not understand that.

```
Companies.update({_id: company._id, }, /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{> company}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="company">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    {{#each tags}}
        {{> tag}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="tag">
    <li><a href="">{{tag}}</a> - {{count}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Have a look at [tags packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=tags), mainly `patrickleet:tags` and using tags with `autoform`. Otherwise, you're on the right track [embedding tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455685/how-to-implement-post-tags-in-mongo).

Comment: No clean solution for that. Check this: https://code4foodblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/meteor-uncaught-error-not-permitted-untrusted-code-may-only-update-documents-by-id-when-update-array-elementusing/

Answer (score 2):

In the html add a unique id to each tag so that the id reveals both the company name and tag name.

Your tag names should not have spaces in them, call them Tag1, Tag2, not Tag 1, Tag 2. Same for the company name, spaces are always a problem. Use 'Company_Name' with an underscore, which you can remove later if need be.

So each tag should have a unique id something like this:

```
<a href="" id="Company_Name.tag1">{{tag}}</a>
```

Then you can get the id of the clicked link from the event, and split the id on the dot to reveal both the company name and the tag name.

---

Then to update the count:

```
Company.update({"name" : "Company 1", 'tags.tag': 'tag 1'}, {$inc: {'tags.$.count': 1}});
```

If Meteor doesn't let you do this then you either: 
put the _id field in your html instead of the company name,

or: 
1) you do a find for the record using the company name 
2) get the _id from the record
3) then update the count using the _id instead of the 'name' field

Comment: Thanks.  As mentioned by others, this raises an error: METEOR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: NOT PERMITTED. UNTRUSTED CODE MAY ONLY UPDATE DOCUMENTS BY ID. Even if the selector includes the company's ID it doesn't work, because it mustn't include anything else than the id. As a workaround, I have to replace the whole tags array.

Answer (score 1):

To update the tag count, something like this should work:

```js
Company.update({
  _id: company._id, 'tags.tag': tagName
}, {
  $inc: {
  'tags.$.count': 1
}});
```

Generally, try to use existing packages. Have a look at [tags packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=tags), mainly `patrickleet:tags` and using tags with `autoform`. Otherwise, you're on the right track [embedding tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455685/how-to-implement-post-tags-in-mongo).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, it raises an error: METEOR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: NOT PERMITTED. UNTRUSTED CODE MAY ONLY UPDATE DOCUMENTS BY ID. As a workaround, I have to replace the whole tags array (and do the actual count increment in plain javascript)

Comment: @Pueggel: I suspect this may a bug with Minimongo. Here's the [issue I filed](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3775).